# Group by time range in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

Basics:
I have a script which counts my visitors. Some useful information is stored in a MySQL database. Now after more than one year I have more than 180'000 data records and the script which reads the actual visitors is very very slow.

I have this script which counts the visitors and checks if it's the same visitor or it's a new visitor. For that I have a time range of 3 hours and only after this range the visit will count another time.

Script:

```
$besucher_query = mysql_query('SELECT `time`, `agent` FROM `besucher` ORDER BY `ip` ASC');
while($besucher = mysql_fetch_array($besucher_query)) {
    $newtime = $besucher['time'];
    $newagent = $besucher['agent'];
    $limit = 3 /*std*/ * 60 /*min*/ * 60 /*sek*/; // three hours before same visitor counts again
    $diff = $newtime - $limit;

    if($oldtime <= $diff or ($oldtime > $diff and $newagent != $oldagent))
        $besucherzahl++;

    $oldtime = $besucher['time'];
    $oldagent = $besucher['agent'];
        }
$anzahl_besucher = $besucherzahl;
echo $anzahl_besucher;
```

I created this script some years ago and I know it's the most ugly way to do this. The time is stored in UNIX Timestamp format.

Now my question:
How can I "group" this with the conditions above (3 hours rule) directly in MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly execute following query from your PHP script to get the total unique visitors for the last 3 hours:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `agent`) AS visitor_count
FROM `besucher`
WHERE `time` >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 3 HOUR);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GROUP BY 10800*FLOOR(`time`/10800)
```

However if you've got records (say) at 2:59 and 3:01, these will be reported as 2 seperate records in the output. If you want to measure contiguous runs, then you'll need to do something similar to your current code - however you can store the results in the DB so as not to calculate them again - just add a new column which references the row designated as the start of the session:

```
ALTER TABLE besucher ADD COLUMN session_start INTEGER;
```

Then....

```
$limit = 3 /*std*/ * 60 /*min*/ * 60 /*sek*/;

$since=(integer)(file_get_contents('lastrun'))-$limit;
$besucher_query = mysql_query('SELECT 
      ip, `time`, `agent` FROM `besucher`
      WHERE `time`>$since 
      ORDER BY agent, ip, `time` ASC');
while($besucher = mysql_fetch_array($besucher_query)) {
   $newtime = $besucher['time'];
   $newagent = $besucher['agent'];
   $newip = $besucher['ip'];

   if ($newagent!=$oldagent 
       || $newip <> $oldip 
       || $newtime>$oldtime+$limit 
       || $newtime<$oldtime) {
     $sessionstart=$newtime;
   }
   $newagent=mysql_real_escape_string($newagent);
   mysql_query(
      "UPDATE besucher SET session_start=$sessionstart
       WHERE time=$newtime AND ip=$newip AND agent='$newagent'"
   );
   $oldtime = $besucher['time'];
   $oldagent = $besucher['agent'];
}
file_put_contents('lastrun', $oldtime);
```

Then you can get the number of sessions from (for example)....

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT ip, agent, session_start
  FROM bessucher
  WHERE time BETWEEN $a AND $b) ilv
```

Bu a simpler solution is to use session management in your code and populate this immediately.